# How do I put Bookdown chapters in a subdirectory?

Tags: r, bookdown

I can't figure put how to make a book with Rmd files in a subdirectory.

Here's my current directory structure:

- myProject.Rproj
- index.RMD
- _bookdown.yml
- chapters/

  - chapt1.RMD
  - chapt2.RMD
  - extraThatShouldNotBeIncluded.RMD

What should go in `_bookdown.yml` and in `index.RMD` to make this work?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that you just have to specify the directory of each RMD in `_bookdown.yml`:

```
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "chapters/chapt1.RMD", "chapters/chapt2.RMD"]
```

Comment: That is right. And there is a feature request to make it easier: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/242 but I don't have time to think about or implement it.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui. I figured out why I was originally confused. This approach does not work when `new_session: yes`.

Comment: @sharoz this is explained in the [book chapter on two rendering approaches](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html) "We call these two approaches “Merge and Knit” (M-K) and “Knit and Merge” (K-M), respectively." "K-M does not allow Rmd files to be in subdirectories, but M-K does."